# Does Aegir 3 allow multiple SSL sites on the same IP Address?

Tags: 7, aegir, ssl

On our server some sites use SSL, some don't, some are Drupal sites, some are not.
All the sites are served at the same IP address and the non-Drupal sites each use their own certificates (or none) per their Apache configuration.

With Aegir 2 it was only possible to have: one IP Address for non-SSL sites and one IP address per each SSL Drupal site which would exhaust our purchased IP addresses.

Does Aegir 3 allow multiple SSL sites / certificates on the same IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it does. From the [release notes](http://community.aegirproject.org/3.0):

> Aegir 3 now supports SNI for SSL.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Clive. Then I shall install and upgrade next week.